# Get sides of triangle with only angle as given?

Tags: trigonometry, education

Can someone tell me how to get the sides of triangle(opposite,adjacent and hypotenuse) if i only have an angle as given? I got the angle by getting using atan2(y-y,x-x); Now i want to get the sides maybe get the hypotenuse first.

What formula should i use? thanks

Comment: In general you can't. Not unless at least one side is given. The angles only determine a triangle up to similarity.

Comment: @DavidH so ah i can only get the angle using x and y? only that? will using pythagorean theorem help me get the hypothenuse so that i can get the opposite?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot fix the lengths of sides of a triangle if the angles are known. You need to know at-least one side in order to find the sides.

Comment: I get the angle using atan2 now i need sides. If i use pythagorean to get hypothenuse is that possible? cause i believe the sum of two sides is equal to hypotenuse?

Comment: what is atan2 ?? Do you have the length of atleast one side ?

Comment: Err no. I get it only using atan2(y-y,x-x). I believe atan2 is like the arctan in programming.

Comment: what is (x,y) ? Is it a point in coordinate geometry ?

Comment: Yes. Yes it is. Its the coordinate of my cursor and my sprite on a 2d plane.

Comment: @Tifa, don't act too cocky. We are trying to help u here

Comment: @user34304 im sorry im not getting too cocky. Im here cause i need help. Im not really sure what part of my comment you find offensive